# Show that collection of finite dimensional cylinder sets is an algebra but not $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to prove that collection of all finite dimensional cylinder sets is an algebra but not $\sigma$-algebra. Cylinder sets are defined as:

$\mathcal{B}_n$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra containing the rectangles $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n): x_1 \in I_1,\ldots,x_n \in I_n \}$ where $I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_n$ are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

An $n$- dimensional  cylinder set in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty} := \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times...$ is defined as the set $\{\textbf{x}: (x_{1},x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in B\},\ B \in \mathcal{B}_n$.

I am unable to visualize how to prove that finite unions belong in the collection, and also why some infinite unions won't belong to the collection.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3):

I presume that by a cylinder set you mean a set of the form $B \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, with $B \in {\cal B_n}$ for some $n$. Let ${\cal C}_n$ denote the $n$ dimensional cylinder sets and ${\cal C} = \cup_n {\cal C}_n$.

Note that if $C \in {\cal C}_n$ then $C \in {\cal C}_m$ for all $m \ge n$.

If $C_1,...,C_k$ are cylinder sets, then all of the sets are in some ${\cal C}_p$ for some $p$, hence $C_1 \cup \cdots \cup C_k \in {\cal C}_p$, hence
${\cal C}$ is closed under finite unions.

It might be easier to show that ${\cal C}$ is not closed under infinite intersections.

Let $C_k = \{0\}\times \cdots\times\{0\} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$ ($k$ zeros), and
note that $C=\cap_k C_k = \{(0,0,0,\cdots) \}$. We see that $C \notin {\cal C}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You mean infinite intersections, right ?

Comment: @AshokVardhan: Yes indeed, I fixed the typo!

Comment: Can we also say that $ \mathcal{C} $ cannot contain any singleton sets using the same logic that $\{(0,0,...\}$ cannot belong ?

Comment: Every element of ${\cal C}$ ends in $\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, so it cannot contain any singleton sets.

Comment: You say "it might be easier" - is it even possible to prove this through unions?

Comment: @DahnJahn: Take $C_1 = \{1\}\times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, $C_2 = \{2\} \times \{2\}\times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, $C_3 = \{3\} \times \{3\}\times \{3\} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$, then $\cup_k C_k$ cannot be a cylinder set.

Comment: But isn't that just $\mathbb N \times \mathbb R^\mathbb N$? This is what confuses me, $\{3\} \cup \mathbb R = \mathbb R$, right? And $\mathbb N$ is Borel, so what am I missing.

Comment: It is $\times$ not $\cup$.

Comment: Well, yes, but say $C_1 \cup C_2 = \{1,2\} \times \mathbb R^\mathbb N$ in my understanding.

Comment: $C_1 \cup C_2$ does not contain the point $(2,1,1,1,1....)$.

Comment: Ah! Heureka moment. Still need some clearing up, but that's mostly to be done in my mind and definitely outside a lengthy comment section, the main point's gotten through. Thanks!